# Unable to connect RDS db using Sql Yog

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have created an RDS instance in aws for Mysql db. But I am unable to connect that server using the Sqlyog

```
Endpoint key is used as host and all the other details are correct.
Also when I go to "Security Groups" it says "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region."
```

Please help me out on this. Thanks a lot